# IndentationError: expected an indented block when use unicode

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block when use unicode

but without:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.BankName
```

it work correctly.

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Bank(models.Model):
    BankName=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CardNum=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.BankName
```

when typing python `manage.py runserver`

```
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x310f450>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/zahra/Web/rezvan/agancy/models.py", line 7
    return  self.BankName
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Please help me.

Comment: In a function block, statements should be indented following the function declaration (the `def` line). Your second code section in your question shows it's not: `def` and `return` have the same indentation. Oddly enough, in your first code block, you have it correct.

Comment: to typing in a function block i make a mistak.
def __unicode__(self):----return sels.name

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces for indentation? Don't do that; use only spaces (preferably 4 per indent block).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
class Bank(models.Model):
    BankName=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CardNum=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.BankName
```

Please [read the Python tutorial sections on control structures, which describes multi-level indentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: same error!!
i make a mistak in typing question and now edit it.my code like yours